# Function returning null in FLutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement the function below but it gives me null.

To be specific, `Future credit()` is not updating the variable value. There is no problem with the database because if I put `print(doc['value'])` instead of `value += doc['value']`, I get the expected result.
It seems, `getCredit()` is the one returning null.

```
Future credit() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    final String uid = user.uid;
    int value = 0;
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('entries')
        .where("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
        .where("type", isEqualTo: "+")
        .orderBy("time", descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) => data.documents.forEach((doc) => value += doc['value']));
    print(value); // doesnt update value
    return value;
  }

  int getCredit() {
    credit().then((value) {print(value);});
    credit().then((value) {return value;});  // return mot working
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. It seems it was a problem with the scope of variable.

```
int cr = 0;
Future credit() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    final String uid = user.uid;
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('entries')
        .where("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
        .where("type", isEqualTo: "+")
        .orderBy("time", descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) => data.documents.forEach((doc) {cr = cr + doc['value'];}));

    print('$cr');
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```dart
Future<int> getCredit() async {
  return await  credit();
}
```